How to make past date hidden in fullcalendar and event draggable function still works? in vue3

I want to make the days before today in this month hidden, but still be able to drag the event.
I already tried use the CSS attribute display:none by classNames but it makes the event undraggable, which doesn't resolve my problem.
Please help me to solve this problem. I am using vue3 and fullCalendar.

I assume you mean that you don't want to be able to drag the event to any day before the today? It would be better simply to stop the user dragging there, rather than trying to hide them. With https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventAllow you can add code to check if the date being dragged to is before today or not, and the calendar can then decide based on that

Stop dragging before today，I've already imposed restrictions. Actually, my requirement is to prevent too many past days grid from affecting the visual effect and drag and drop experience of users

How is the past days affecting anything like that?? The problem is not clear. And even if you hide the days they will just be hidden. It would not change the layout of the calendar. The other days would still be in the same place. I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve, or why
